# Caret character between types rather than variables, surrounded by parentheses

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks, caret

I was going through Apple's documentation and I saw something like this `(void (^)(void))`. Can somebody explain what this statement means? `^` is XOR, right? `void XOR void` doesn't makes much sense to me?

There was also something like `(void (^)(BOOL finished))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are blocks which add anonymous functions and function objects to Objective-C. See e.g. [Introducing Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch](https://web.archive.org/web/20100114164121/http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/cocoa/introblocksgcd.html) :

> Block objects (informally, “blocks”) are an extension to C, as well as Objective-C and C++, that make it easy for programmers to define self-contained units of work. Blocks are similar to — but far more powerful than — traditional function pointers. The key differences are:
>
> - Blocks can be defined inline, as “anonymous functions.”
> - Blocks capture read-only copies of local variables, similar to “closures” in other languages

Declaring a block variable:

```
void (^my_block)(void);
```

Assigning a block object to it:

```
my_block = ^(void){ printf("hello world\n"); };
```

Invoking it:

```
my_block(); // prints “hello world\n”
```

Accepting a block as an argument:

```
- (void)doSomething:(void (^)(void))block;
```

Using that method with an inline block:

```
[obj doSomeThing:^(void){ printf("block was called"); }];
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a [block](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/cocoa/introblocksgcd.html), an Apple-specific extension to C, similar to function pointers, or function objects in other languages.

`(void (^)(void))` looks like a typecast to the type of a block that takes no parameters and returns nothing. Similarly, `(void (^)(BOOL finished))` looks like another typecast, to a block with one boolean parameter and returning nothing.