# Preprocessor macro using caret ^ symbol at the start of an expression

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-blocks, caret

Looking at this page: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-12-31-c-macro-tips-and-tricks.html

I found this snippet of code with `^{` ... `}()` syntax, what are the caret/brackets doing?

```
#define MAX(x, y) (^{ \
    int my_localx = (x); \
    int my_localy = (y); \
    return my_localx > my_localy ? (my_localx) : (my_localy); \
}())
```

It looks like its creating an anonymous function or something. What is this concept called? Where can I read about it?

Comment: FYI, it's "caret," not "carrot."  ;)

Comment: @Jeff, you have plenty of rep to fix that...

Comment: This is a really dumb example since it could be achieved just as well with a perfectly standard `static inline` function. The only benefit of the macro is type-generic programming, which they ruined with fixed-type local vars...

Comment: @Carl: It was important for him to know about but not enough that it needed fixing.  Hence the non-edit, comment only...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caret character between types rather than variables, surrounded by parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079624/caret-character-between-types-rather-than-variables-surrounded-by-parentheses)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a C block. It's quite like an anonymous function (in use, not in structure). You can read more about them on Mike Ash's site and in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html).

Comment: @Heath It is supported by LLVM (and maybe recent versions of gcc) in C and C++ (and Objective-C++). As ldav1s mentioned, it's not standard (yet).

Comment: @CajunLuke - oh good. I was getting worried that with 20years of C experience I didn't know what this did!

Comment: @CajunLuke, cool maybe we can get that standardized, along with ```__try``` and ```declspec```.

Answer (score 3):

It's a block. It's not standard C, but it is supported by Apple's LLVM compiler (around about Xcode 3.2 IIRC and later).  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) and [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt) for more details.

It's not *just* for Objective-C, but is part of the C and C++ compilers also.

Answer (score 1):

[Official Apple Documentation on C Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a C block, which will create an anonimous function.

Note that it will create calls to the system API to handle those calls, don't know about mac, but for iOS, the runtime system must be 3.2 or later to support those calls.