# What does the ^ symbol refer to in the manpage for scandir_b?

Tags: c

From "[man 3 scandir](https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scandir/)" on Mac OS:

```
int
  scandir_b(const char *dirname, struct dirent ***namelist,
    int (^select)(const struct dirent *),
    int (^compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

```
The scandir_b() function works the same way as the scandir() function,
except that select and compar are blocks instead of subroutines.
```

For comparison, the definition for `scandir` is almost the same, except instead of `scandir_b`'s `^`, there are `*`, indicating function pointers.

I'm having trouble find references online or in Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" (K&R) that indicate what the `^` syntax here means (in the grammar defined in K&R `^` seems to be used only for XOR), and what the description means by "blocks instead of subroutines." The only references to "blocks" I can find in K&R are regarding compound statements, e.g.

```
{
  statement;
  statement;
}
```

I also haven't been able to find usage examples of scandir_b that might indicate what these arguments are.

What does the "^" syntax here represent, and what does the description mean by "blocks instead of subroutines?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preprocessor macro using caret ^ symbol at the start of an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852291/preprocessor-macro-using-caret-symbol-at-the-start-of-an-expression).  It's a "caret" symbol.  See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html

Comment: This is a *clang* extension for code blocks added by Apple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)

Comment: It’s an Apple extension over standard C. You won’t find it described in normal C manuals.