# C function prototype has (^) in a formal parameter?

Tags: c

I am writing a program to do a some analysis of C code, and as a part of that I need to parse C source files. On mac I notice that in some of the standard library headers that are included there are function prototypes like the following:

```
void *bsearch_b(const void *,
                const void *,
                size_t,
                size_t,
                int (^)(const void *, const void *)) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.6)));
```

What is the `(^)`? I recognize most of the function pointer syntax in this example, but I have never seen `(^)` used in code.

Comment: That's not standard C.

Comment: That's not standard C. In C `^` is the bitwise xor operator; it's not valid in this context. Perhaps it's Objective-C?

Comment: Since you're reading Mac headers, it could be [an extension named Blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079624/caret-character-between-types-rather-than-variables-surrounded-by-parentheses). See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29) on the subject.