# '^' in func pointer declaration

Tags: c++

In <stdlib.h> in Mac OS, I saw something like this:

```
int atexit_b(void (^)(void)) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.6)));
void *bsearch_b(const void *, const void *, size_t,
 size_t, int (^)(const void *, const void *)) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.6)));
```

So what does '^' in these declaration mean? Really appreciate if some one can help me here.

Comment: It means *declare atexit_b as function (block (void) returning void) returning int* as pointed [here](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+atexit_b%28void+%28%5E%29%28void%29%29) in [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/).

Comment: Not a C++ construct. Might be from Objective-C, maybe someone can confirm it and retag the question if that's the case?

Comment: @BatCoder: And what exactly does *"block (void) returning void"* mean?

Comment: Seems to be answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079624/caret-character-between-types-rather-than-variables-surrounded-by-parentheses).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, a combination of md5i's and my answer . :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the C and C++ standard headers aren't constrained to portable C and C++; they often contain compiler-specific stuff. In fact, one reason for putting things into the standard library is that they can't be implemented portably.